# intellij shortcut for creating method stub

Tags: intellij-idea

I've recently switched over to intellij for scala development.

I'm having trouble finding the following shortcut:

In eclipse, I could type a method call e.g.

```
method("hello", 1)
```

and press `<command>1` to have eclipse popup a suggestion to let me create a method stub.

Is there such a shortcut in intellij?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Activate [Type aware highlighting](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Type-aware+highlighting) (See the `[T]` symbol in the image) and
- Set Highlighting level to *Inspections*

Then it is possible to use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in Eclipse) to show menu, which has *create method* option.

[image]

### Why isn't it enabled by default?

> **The feature is in beta** (or maybe in alpha) and sometimes may report "false errors" in regular code. Usually, such "errors" "found" only in a truly complex code, and, normally, everything works just fine.
>
> Scala plugin doesn't rely on compiler to analyze code. We're implementing our own model of the language, and sometimes it's challenging, especially when it comes to Scala's type system and type inference (to size up the problem, you may try to formally "infer" a type of "foo".map(_ + 1) expression by hand).

Answer (score 14):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (**Show Intention Actions** in `Settings` | `Keymap`).

Verified, works fine in IDEA 11.0.1 with the current Scala plug-in:
[image: create method]

Comment: I'm on a mac. I have tried with different keysmappings for show intentions. Nothing happens

Comment: Maybe it's not supported for Scala yet.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder, can you please verify with your team that its not available for scala? thanks!

Comment: Hmm... nope i have reinstalled, still nothing. What plugins do I need for it to work? I have ultimate edition 11.01. I already have sbt, scala plugins installed.

Comment: No other plug-ins are required. Did you try to remap this action to some other hotkey?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7119/discussion-between-crazycoder-and-dzhu)